# How to get output from file to have commas between the elements?

Tags: python

I would like to add commas between the elements in the file. Right now it outputs all crammed together. This is part of a larger program. Can anyone help?

code:

```
def export_emp():
    f = open('output.txt','a+')
    for i in range (len(employee_List)):
        f.write(str(employee_List[i][0]))
        f.write(str(employee_List[i][1]))
        f.write(str(employee_List[i][2]))
        f.write(str(employee_List[i][3]))
        f.write(str(employee_List[i][4]))
    f.close()

def add_empFile():
    output=open('output.txt','r')
    file=output.read()
    output.close()
    print(file)
```

Comment: I apologize for the format...it is correct in my program, I just have issues placing it in here. I am still getting the hang of this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a comma to the end of the `write()` content, like so:

```
f.write(str(employee_List[i][0]) + ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to add commas in the file:

```
def write_to_file(file,text):
  if text is not None:
     file.write(text+",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join with comma and write to file at the end:

```
with open('output.txt','a+') as f:
    for x in employee_List:
        to_save = ', '.join([str(x[i]) for i in range(5)])
        f.write(to_save)
```

Also, use `with open(...)` to open file, so you don't need to worry about closing the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add commas between all employee_List,
you can just iterate all element in employee_List and use join method to add commas, 
don't need to specify all index when concatenate them.

```
def export_emp():
    with open('output.txt','a+') as f:
        string = ','.join([str(x) for x in employee_List])
        f.write(string)
```